# Android Keystore

Tags: java, android, keystore, android-keystore

I've taken over an Android application from another developer, they've provided me with the keystore file but it has a `.txt` file extension (not `.jks` or `.keystore`). When I try to use it with the Alias/Password I'm getting an error. I ran it through keytool to try and pull the info but i'm getting `java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format`.

- The app is already on google play.
- I've already tried changing the file extension manually.

Is there any way to get this file back into the correct format or sign my app with the `.txt` version?

Thanks!

Comment: This maybe a dumb question, but have you tried renaming the extension to .jks or .keystore?, it could of been renamed so that it could be uploaded (some corporate emails block certain extensions).

Comment: Hi, yes I changed this manually (edited my question just before you replied!), no luck unfortunately.

Comment: If it doesn't work with the `keytool`, as either a JKS or a PKCS#12 format, it *isn't* a keystore. Ask the developer what it is.

Comment: Hi, Did you solve the issue of keystore with the text file?

Comment: I didn't unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

If you have source code and app is not already on play store with same package name then just forget old `keystore`,  you can create a new  `keystore` and sign app then upload to Play Store.

**Updated:**

as you updated your question,so Im updating my answer. So, Your app is already on Play store and you lost your signing `keystore` but if your App is enrolled in Google Play Signing program then you can request Google to reset.

> If you lose your keystore or think it may be compromised, Google Play
>   App Signing makes it possible to request a reset to your upload key.
>   If you're not enrolled in Google Play App Signing and lose your
>   keystore, you'll need to publish a new app with a new package name

for More details Read this official [Docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en)

Comment: Good point, but worth remembering to check any additional 3rd party integrations i.e facebook SDK, that require upload of the signing key's signature hash. These would need to be changed to.

Comment: @AlexBrown then its not your fault. Ask them to provide proper keystore.

Comment: You can't just 'create a new keystore'. You have to import the existing private key and certificate into it, and the only places they exist are in the old keystore, and if you can read the old keystore why would you need to create a new one?

Comment: @EJP , he is not able to read old one, thats why I suggested in the case if App is not already on Play Store

Comment: I agree. He can't read the old one. So he can't import the old private key or certificate or signing chain. So how does creating a new keystore, with a new private key, a new certificate, and a new signing chain, solve anything?

Comment: @EJP If he lost old one then its means he lost his control on App on Play store. He has to go from start upload app with New package name and maybe new App name and new Signing. There is no other way.